# Clojure, assoc in Okasaki trie using recur

Tags: clojure, refactoring

I naively implemented the trie from Okasaki's book "Purely Functional Data Structures" in Clojure. Just for learning purposes, because probably there is no real gain, since Clojure used a more efficient trie under the hood of normal maps, right? There is one thing that still bothers me about it: trie-assoc doesn't use `recur`. How could I refactor it so it only does a recursive call on the tail using `recur`? I have the feeling I could use zippers for this, but I haven't looked into zippers that much yet.
One other thing that maybe could be improved is the (if (empty? key) ...) followed by a destructuring on key. Could this be more concise?

```
(ns okasaki-trie.core)

(def empty-trie {:value nil :nodes nil})

(defn trie-get [key trie]
  (if (empty? key) (get trie :value)
      (let [[k & ks] key]
        (recur ks (get-in trie [:nodes k])))))

(defn trie-assoc [key val trie]
  (if (empty? key) (assoc trie :value val) 
      (let [[k & ks] key
            sub-trie-k (or (get-in trie [:nodes k]) empty-trie)
            sub-trie-k-new (trie-assoc ks val sub-trie-k)]
        (assoc-in trie [:nodes k] sub-trie-k-new))))

;;(def first-trie (trie-assoc "a" 3 empty-trie))
;;first-trie => {:nodes {\a {:nodes nil, :value 3}}, :value nil}

;;(def second-trie (trie-assoc "ab" 5 first-trie))
;;second-trie => {:nodes {\a {:nodes {\b {:nodes nil, :value 5}},
;;:value 3}}, :value nil}

;;(def third-trie (trie-assoc "b" 2 second-trie))
;;third-trie  => {:nodes {\b {:nodes nil, :value 2}, \a {:nodes {\b
;;{:nodes nil, :value 5}}, :value 3}}, :value nil}

;;(trie-get "b" third-trie)  ;=> 2
;;(trie-get "ab" third-trie) ;=> 5
;;(trie-get "abc" third-trie)  ;=> nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't looked deeply into this algorithm, but I doubt if tail recursion is (usefully) possible. You have to walk down a tree, and then back up it to reconstruct the nodes on the path to the root. This requires a stack, hence no `recur`.

If you want, you can manage your own "stack" on the heap, by keeping a list of parent-nodes and manually walking them back to the root. Then you can use `recur` and avoid stack overflows, but you won't be using any less memory (probably more, really). So this is only a useful trick if you have trees with 2^1000 elements in them (and I rather doubt that you do).

#### Edit

Just noticed your question about

```
(if (empty? key)
  (...empty...)
  (let [[k & ks] key]
    (...more...)))
```

You can rewrite this more simply and concisely as:

```
(if-let [[k & ks] (seq key)]
  (...more...)
  (...empty...))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is both necromancy, and a tad off-topic, but I came across this question exploring implementing a trie in Clojure. I was compelled by tying to implement with immutability. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
(def  trie (atom {}))
(defn key-list     [s    ] (into [] (map str s)))
(defn trie-add     [t k v] (assoc-in t (conj (key-list k) :v) v))
(defn trie-query   [t k  ] (get-in (deref t) (conj (key-list k) :v)))
(defn trie-subtree [t k  ] (get-in (deref t) (key-list k)))
```

which provides a surprisingly clean implementation, so I wanted to share.

For cut-and-paste exploration:

```
(swap! trie trie-add "aac" 1)
(swap! trie trie-add "abc" 4)
(swap! trie trie-add "ab" 5)
(swap! trie trie-add "oaailfnalieuhkakjdfkjh" 1)
(swap! trie trie-add "aaailfnalieuhkakjdfkjh" 1)
(swap! trie trie-add "oaailfnalieancbnwiuybw" 1)
(swap! trie trie-add "oa" 3)

(trie-query trie "ab")
(trie-query trie "abc")
(trie-query trie "oaailfnalie")
(trie-query trie "oa")
(trie-query trie "oaailfnalieuhkakjdfkjh")

(trie-subtree trie "oa")
(trie-subtree trie "a")
(trie-subtree trie "oaailfnalieancbnwiuyb")
(trie-subtree trie "oaailfnalieancbnwiuy")
(trie-subtree trie "oaailfnalieancbnwiu")

(deref trie)
```

good times. Maybe this answers the "Could this be more concise" question.